# Problem using struct array for reading from file

Tags: c

In function read_conf function, I read from the config file and when I use the print function it displays the the structs as desired.

When I call the Display function, then there is problem reading as it displays only the last entry in read function.

```
   struct {
     char *ext;
     char *filetype;
    } extensions [10];

void read_conf()
{
 char buf[BUFSIZE];
 char *free1 = NULL;
 char *free2 = NULL;
 FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("config.conf", "r");
 int i_mime = 0;
 while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf), fp))
 {
  if(!strncmp(buf,"Listen ",7))
  {
   Port_serv_list = &buf[7];   
   printf("Port number read from conf file is : %s\n", Port_serv_list);
  }  
  if(!strncmp(buf,"DocumentRoot ",13))
  {
   Dir = &buf[13];   
   printf("Directory read from conf file is : %s\n", Dir);
  }  
  if (buf[0] == '.')
  {  
   free1 = strtok(buf," ");   
   extensions[i_mime].ext = &free1[1];

   free2 = strtok(NULL," "); 
   extensions[i_mime].filetype = free2;
   printf("ext: %s\n",extensions[i_mime].ext);
   printf("filetype: %s\n%d\n",extensions[i_mime].filetype, i_mime);
   i_mime++;   
   //printf("Data from conf file \": %s\n",buf);
  }
 }
}

void Display_Content_Conf()
{
 int j_mime = 0;
 printf("Displaying content of Extension Structure array:""\n");
 for(j_mime;j_mime<=7;j_mime++)
 {
  printf("ext: %s\n",extensions[j_mime].ext);
  printf("filetype: %s\n%d\n",extensions[j_mime].filetype, j_mime);
 }
}
```

Output:

```
ext: htm
filetype: text/html

0
ext: html
filetype: text/html

1
ext: txt
filetype: text/plain

2
ext: jpeg
filetype: image/jpeg

3
ext: jpg
filetype: image/jpeg

4
ext: png
filetype: image/png

5
ext: gif
filetype: image/gif

6
ext: bmp
filetype: image/bmp

7
```

Displaying content of Extension Structure array:

```
ext: bmp
filetype: image/bmp

0
ext: bmp
filetype: mage/bmp

1
ext: bmp
filetype: image/bmp

2
ext: bmp
filetype: mage/bmp

3
ext: bmp
filetype: image/bmp

4
ext: bmp
filetype: image/bmp

5
ext: bmp
filetype: image/bmp

6
ext: bmp
filetype: image/bmp

7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the pointers in the `extensions` structure are left pointing into `buf`, which is being overwritten on each pass through the loop (and deallocated on exiting `read_conf`, so the fact that you're seeing anything valid at all is undefined behavior).

You'll need to call `strdup` on the strings returned from `strtok` to get them into newly allocated dynamic memory in order to store them safely.  Something like this:

```
free1 = strtok(buf," ");   
extensions[i_mime].ext = strdup(&free1[1]);

free2 = strtok(NULL," "); 
extensions[i_mime].filetype = strdup(free2);
```

Just remember to `free()` the strings returned by `strdup` when you no longer need them.  If by some stroke of ill luck your C environment doesn't provide a `strdup` function (it's not in ANSI C but *is* in POSIX), you can supply it -- it's rather simple:

```
/* Duplicates a supplied string. */
char *strdup(const char *input)
{
    /* Required buffer size is the string length, plus 1 for terminator. */
    size_t size = strlen(input) + 1;

    /* Allocate buffer.  If it fails, return NULL for failure. */
    char *dup = (char *) malloc(size);
    if (dup == NULL) return NULL;

    /* Now copy the string data into the newly allocated buffer and return it. */
    memcpy(dup, input, size);
    return dup;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, strdup is an extension.

Comment: @Null Set Okay, I've attached an ANSI C implementation of `strdup`.  Satisfied? ;-)